# Show Hide elements Meteor way

Tags: meteor

I have `table` with a lot of `tr`, when my page is load **1st** tr shows and **2nd** tr is hide, for example:

```
<table>
  <tr></tr> // shows
  <tr></tr> // hide
  <tr></tr> // shows
  <tr></tr> // hide
  ...
  ...
  etc.
</table>
```

**What I want to build:** When you click on "show" tr, lower tr (which is located underneath) must shows too, and when you clicked on "NEW" shows tr it must hide (like toggle)

**PROBLEM:** When I clcked on "show" tr, ALL "hide" tr shows too, **NOT** one which is located underneath

**My CODE:**

```
<template name="postJobs">
  <tr class="smallInfo">
    // some code
  </tr>
  {{#if showFullContent}}
  <tr class=" bigInfo">
    // some code
  </tr>
  {{/if}}
</template>


Template.postJobs.helpers({
  showFullContent:function(){
    return Session.get('showContent');
   }
});

Template.postJobs.events({
  'click .smallInfo':function(){
    Session.set('showContent',true);
  },
  'click .bigInfo':function(){
    Session.set('showContent',false);
  },
});
```

I dont want to use jQuery

Comment: Saimeunt's answer looks like what you want. For more information see [this article](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you're using `Session`, which is a global reactive dictionary, meaning that you only end up storing one state for all of your table rows.

Here is a solution using a template scoped `ReactiveVar` object :

HTML

```
<template name="jobsTable">
  <table>
    {{#each jobs}}
      {{> postJobs}}
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</template>

<template name="postJobs">
  <tr class="smallInfo">
    // some code
  </tr>
  {{#if showFullContent}}
    <tr class=" bigInfo">
      // some code
    </tr>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.postJobs.onCreated(function(){
  this.showFullContent = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.postJobs.helpers({
  showFullContent: function(){
    return Template.instance().showFullContent.get();
  }
});

Template.postJobs.events({
  "click .smallInfo": function(event, template){
    template.showFullContent.set(true);
  },
  "click .bigInfo": function(event, template){
    template.showFullContent.set(false);
  }
});
```

Comment: You'll need to run  meteor add reactive-var if you haven't already as per https://forums.meteor.com/t/uncaught-referenceerror-reactivevar-is-not-defined/11406/2